# Window manipulation software

Tags: window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do any window managers allow me to snap windows to the sides of the display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/850/do-any-window-managers-allow-me-to-snap-windows-to-the-sides-of-the-display)

I was wondering if there is software out there that will make OS X windows act like Windows 7. For instance, you can "bump" a window at the top of the screen and it will fill the screen. Or, "bumping" the left/right will make the window become half-screen.

Comment: Wouldnt it be a better question if you asked for all the software that can do this? It's a rare time when someone prefers paid over a free solution that has no drawbacks. Those on a budget can make a better choice if they can afford the best or make do with the free? Everyone can vote the best and you can always choose the free and comment why later...

Comment: Hmm...that's true, I'll edit it.

Comment: Slightly more generic question that should cover this topic: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a nice app for these functions! It's called [cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) and it is aviable in the appstore for 7$ (but you can also use the demo)

Comment: What features does the demo not have?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Every so often, the software displays a reminder to buy the software.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Cinch that is less mouse-based and more keyboard-based is DoublePane. It is available in the Mac App Store. It provides you with easy keyboard shortcuts to place windows side-by-side, full screen or back to their original positions. It is inexpensive and works as advertised. Hope this helps.