# Macbook external display rearranges homescreen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I've just set my PC moniter as primary screen when I plug in my MacBook (Air 2020) but it keeps rearranging my Homescreen.

When I rearrange it so it fits my external display and unplug my laptop it will place the apps on top of each other so I that doesn't work.

Can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What does rearrange your Home Screen mean in practice? Quite a few things have to change when a new display is added. Some things can optionally change. We don’t know what you want the result to look like based on the initial wording of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a laptop with its own screen, as soon as you unplug your Primary screen, the internal once again becomes Primary & all windows will migrate to it.

Re-connecting the other display it will then once again reassign it as Primary - but the 'damage' has already been done & it will not be able to correctly place the windows back where they were.

You may benefit from using a third party window manager. There are a few listed in the answers to this question - [Do any window managers allow me to snap windows to the sides of the display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/850/do-any-window-managers-allow-me-to-snap-windows-to-the-sides-of-the-display)